# C++ concept to enforce field of particular type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'd like to define a concept that enforces that a structure has a field of type `int` called `refcnt`.  Unfortunately, I'm getting unexpected results when compiling with gcc 10.2.0 and clang 11.0.1.  Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <stdio.h>

struct S {
  int refcnt;
};

template<typename T>
concept HasRefcnt1 = requires(T t) {
  { t.refcnt } -> std::same_as<int&>;
};

template<typename T>
concept HasRefcnt2 = requires(T t) {
  { t.refcnt } -> std::integral;
};

int
main()
{
#define TEST(N)                                 \
  if constexpr (HasRefcnt##N<S>)                \
    printf("HasRefcnt" #N "<S>\n")
  TEST(1);
  TEST(2);
}
```

Now here's what I get when I run the program:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Werror constraint.cc
$ ./a.out 
HasRefcnt1<S>
$ clang++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Werror constraint.cc
$ ./a.out 
HasRefcnt2<S>
```

So basically gcc likes the first constraint, and clang likes the second.  My questions:

1. Which (if either) of the compilers is correct?
2. What's the easiest reliable way to define a concept that requires a struct to have fields of particular names with particular types?

**update**

For now, I've found that the following works on both compilers, so maybe that's good enough.  However, I haven't seen example code like this, which makes me suspect there's a better way to do it:

```
template<typename T>
concept HasRefcnt3 = requires(T t) {
  static_cast<int&>(t.refcnt);
};
```

Comment: gcc is correct, this is [clang bug 45088](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45088)

Comment: @Barry Why is `int` not an `integral` type?

Comment: `int` is an `integral` type, but that's not what you're checking - you're checking `integral<decltype((t.refcnt))>` which is `integral<int&>`.